# can't paste in vim SunOS (nothing in register)

Tags: unix, vim

I am not sure what I do wrong. It appears that yanking works fine, but when hitting p to paste, I get:
E353: nothing in register "

I do:

```
vim myFile
V
y
:q!
vim temp
p
```

What am I missing?

SunOS myServer 5.10 Generic_142900-04 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise

Comment: Which version of vim are you using?

Comment: can you check your `.viminfo` file after you yank the text and then quit `vim`?

Comment: $ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Feb 22 2009 06:30:54)
Compiled by steve@v480
Normal version with GTK GUI.

Comment: I am not familiar with this. How can I check my .viminfo? It seems like there is no such a file for me.

Comment: that's probably the reason your paste is not working. between different vim sessions registers are saved to the `~/.viminfo` in your home directory. without that file register contents would be lost..

Comment: @user1006375 please post the resolution as an answer, for other people to notice

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. Thanks for the directions... I looked up this thread: Copy and paste in vim via keyboard between different mac terminals?

and it turned out tehre was no .vimrc in my home dir. So I created on and added this line to it:

set clipboard+=unnamed

and after sourcing that file, I could paste between different vim sessions (in one terminal at least).